# How do I perform this sed command with bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I have a file full of usernames and I want to use sed to change the usernames to `PLAYER 1-20` how can I do this with a bash script and sed while incrementing?

I have this so far:

```bash
NAME=$(grep -q 'Seat' ${POKER_HAND} | awk '{print $3}')
POKER_HAND=/vagrant/sample.txt #Change to your file name
OUTPUT_FILE=/vagrant/poker-output.txt #Change where you want to output

if grep -q "${NAME}" "${POKER_HAND}"; then
  sed -r "s/${NAME}/PLAYER/g" ${POKER_HAND} > file.txt
fi
```

`Sample.txt`:

```
PokerStars Hand #241801691187: Hold'em No Limit ($0.05/$0.10 USD) - 2023/02/12 19:59:19 ET
Table 'Alcathous' 6-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 1: lladnar1130 ($9.73 in chips)
Seat 3: javier_jia ($10 in chips)
Seat 5: C.Luz7 ($22 in chips)
Seat 6: calojoai4 ($11.55 in chips)
C.Luz7: posts small blind $0.05
calojoai4: posts big blind $0.10
*** HOLE CARDS ***
lladnar1130: folds
javier_jia: raises $0.14 to $0.24
C.Luz7: folds
calojoai4: folds
Uncalled bet ($0.14) returned to javier_jia
javier_jia collected $0.25 from pot
javier_jia: doesn't show hand
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot $0.25 | Rake $0
Seat 1: lladnar1130 folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 3: javier_jia (button) collected ($0.25)
Seat 5: C.Luz7 (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 6: calojoai4 (big blind) folded before Flop
```

What the bash script should do after being parsed:

```
PokerStars Hand #241801691187: Hold'em No Limit ($0.05/$0.10 USD) - 2023/02/12 19:59:19 ET
Table 'Alcathous' 6-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 1: Player1 ($9.73 in chips)
Seat 3: Player2 ($10 in chips)
Seat 5: Player3 ($22 in chips)
Seat 6: Player4 ($11.55 in chips)
Player3: posts small blind $0.05
Player4: posts big blind $0.10
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Player1: folds
Player2: raises $0.14 to $0.24
Player3: folds
Player4: folds
Uncalled bet ($0.14) returned to Player2
Player2 collected $0.25 from pot
Player2: doesn't show hand
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot $0.25 | Rake $0
Seat 1: Player1 folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 3: Player2 (button) collected ($0.25)
Seat 5: Player3 (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 6: Player4 (big blind) folded before Flop
```

Comment: Hello, hard to say without seeing any sort of exemplary data as your attempt looks potentially completely wrong since you e.g. define `POKER_HAND` after using it in `NAME`. Include the data please, but I'd recommend learning any sort of bash basics instead, for what I'm assuming is a homework. A simple loop solution should be sufficient here.

Comment: what type of loop would I need to use and how because I forgot how to do bash

Comment: If you want to remember player names for each seat then that's a completely different thing and your script wasn't even close. Let me see if I can craft anything after I return home.

Comment: Bash;  www.tldp.org has at least two "Bash guides". Already skimming through these will give you hints on what and how you can do things.

Comment: can you show me the sed command to find and replace the names